# Convert string type column to struct and unzip the column using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input DF:

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|rowNum|infoCol                                              |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|100   |[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase')]|
|200   |[('doe', 'customer')]                                |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

```
root
 |-- rowNum: string (nullable = false)
 |-- infoCol: string (nullable = false)
```

(expected) Output DF:

```
+------+--------+-----------------+
|rowNum|customer|         purchase|
+------+--------+-----------------+
|   100|['john']|['abc, mno, xyz']|
|   100| ['doe']|             null|
+------+--------+-----------------+
```

I have tried using the `split` function but that doesn't quite do what I need.

```
inputdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("100", "[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase')]"),
        ("200", "[('doe', 'customer')]"),
    ],
    ['rowNum', 'infoCol'] 
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, split
outputdf = inputdf.withColumn("newcol", split(col("infoCol"), ","))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try with **`spark built`** in functions.

Idea here is first create **`2 columns`** with `customer,purchase` as values and other values in another column, to get these columns I used split then explode.

Once we got **`customer,purchase`** values then **`groupBy+Piv`ot** to pivot the data finally split the **columns to get array**.

**`Example:`**

```
inputdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("100", "[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase')]"),
        ("200", "[('doe', 'customer')]"),
    ],
    ['rowNum', 'infoCol'] 
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

inputdf.withColumn("newcol", split(col("infoCol"), "\),")).\
selectExpr("explode(newcol)","rowNum").\
withColumn("newCol1",split(regexp_replace(col("col"),"[\[|\]|\(|\)]",""),"',")).\
withColumn("new1",regexp_replace(trim(element_at(col("newCol1"),1)),"[']","")).\
withColumn("new2",regexp_replace(trim(element_at(col("newCol1"),2)),"[']","")).\
groupby("rowNum").\
pivot("new2").\
agg(first(col("new1"))).\
withColumn("customer",split(col("customer"),",")).\
withColumn("purchase",split(col("purchase"),",")).\
show()

#+------+--------+-----------------+
#|rowNum|customer|         purchase|
#+------+--------+-----------------+
#|   200|   [doe]|             null|
#|   100|  [john]|[abc,  mno,  xyz]|
#+------+--------+-----------------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

```
inputdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("100", "[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase')]"),
        ("200", "[('doe', 'customer')]"),
    ],
    ['rowNum', 'infoCol'] 
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

inputdf.withColumn("newcol", split(col("infoCol"), "\),")).\
selectExpr("explode(newcol)","rowNum").\
withColumn("newCol1",split(regexp_replace(col("col"),"[\[|\]|\(|\)]",""),"',")).\
withColumn("new1",regexp_replace(trim(element_at(col("newCol1"),1)),"[']","")).\
withColumn("new2",regexp_replace(trim(element_at(col("newCol1"),2)),"[']","")).\
groupby("rowNum").\
pivot("new2").\
agg(first(col("new1"))).\
withColumn("customer",col("customer")).\
withColumn("purchase",col("purchase")).\
show()

#+------+--------+-------------+
#|rowNum|customer|     purchase|
#+------+--------+-------------+
#|   200|     doe|         null|
#|   100|    john|abc, mno, xyz|
#+------+--------+-------------+
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
inputdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("100", "[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase'), ('abc123', 'purchase')]"),
        ("200", "[('doe', 'customer')]"),
    ],
    ['rowNum', 'infoCol'] 
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *


inputdf.withColumn("newcol", split(col("infoCol"), "\),")).\
selectExpr("explode(newcol)","rowNum").\
withColumn("newCol1",expr("""transform(split(regexp_replace(col,"[\[|\]|\(|\)]",""),"',"),x -> regexp_replace(trim(x),"[']",""))""")).\
withColumn("new1",regexp_replace(element_at(col("newCol1"),-1),"[\]]","")).\
withColumn("new2",array_except(col("newCol1"),array(lit('purchase'),lit('customer'),lit('purchase]'),lit('customer]')))).\
withColumn("new2",expr("""transform(new2,x -> concat("'",regexp_replace(x,"[\\\\[]",""),"'"))""")).\
drop(*['col','newCol1']).\
groupby("new1","rowNum").agg(flatten(collect_list(col("new2"))).alias("new2")).\
groupby("rowNum").pivot("new1").agg(first(col("new2"))).\
show(10,False)

#+------+--------+---------------------------+
#|rowNum|customer|purchase                   |
#+------+--------+---------------------------+
#|200   |['doe'] |null                       |
#|100   |['john']|['abc, mno, xyz', 'abc123']|
#+------+--------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks! @484 only issue being - 'abc,  mno,  xyz' is getting split out into 3 items. is there something we can do to handle that?

Comment: @thecoder, do u need them as one item? i.e string type?

Comment: @thecoder, Check the edited answer `update` section..

Comment: I'm expecting the final output columns: customer, and purchase to be arrays. So for e.g. [('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase'), ('abc123', 'purchase')], purchase column would have ['abc, mno, xyz', 'abc123'] - which is why arrays would be good.

Comment: @thecoder, Check the edited answer `update2` section..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try and this can be used with many columns not only with `customer`, `purchase` but if the column name is on the last.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = inputdf \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.regexp_replace('infoCol', '[\[\]]', '')) \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.regexp_replace('infoCol', '(\),)', ') ,')) \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.explode(f.split('infoCol', ' , '))) \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.regexp_replace('infoCol', '[\(\)]', '')) \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.regexp_replace('infoCol', '(\',)', '\' ,')) \
  .withColumn('cols', f.split('infoCol', ' , ')[1]) \
  .withColumn('cols', f.regexp_replace('cols', '\'', '')) \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.split('infoCol', ' , ')[0]) \
  .withColumn('infoCol', f.concat(f.lit('['), f.col('infoCol'), f.lit(']'))) \

values = df.select('cols').distinct().rdd.map(lambda x: x.cols).collect()

df.groupBy('rowNum') \
  .pivot('cols', values) \
  .agg(f.first('infoCol')) \
  .show(10, False)

+------+--------+-----------------+
|rowNum|customer|purchase         |
+------+--------+-----------------+
|200   |['doe'] |null             |
|100   |['john']|['abc, mno, xyz']|
+------+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: thanks @lamanus! the output isn't the same as expected as "abc, mno, xyz" is split out into 3 elements instead of one value. also there seems to be an issue if i change ("100", "[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase')]") -> ("100", "[('john', 'customer'), ('abc, mno, xyz', 'purchase'), ('abccc', 'purchase')]")

Comment: Changed. more straight forward but too special